# Keep only first appearance of a value until it changes to another value

Tags: pandas

I have data set that looks as this:

```
 id      mz_id      time        duration
  1        a        0:00           0:10
  1        a        0:01           0:10
  1        a        0:05           0:10
  1        a        0:07           0:10
  1        a        0:09           0:10
  1        b        5:10           1:10
  1        b        15:10          1:10
  1        b        35:10          1:10
  1        a        1:10:05        0:15
  1        a        1:20:07        0:15
  1        b        2:10:05        1:10
  1        c        3:20:07        0:15
```

and so on..

I want to keep first appearance of the value mz_id, to look like this:

```
 id      mz_id      time        duration
  1        a        0:00           0:10
  1        b        5:10           1:10
  1        a        1:10:05        0:15
  1        b        2:10:05        1:10
  1        c        3:20:07        0:15
```

The pair mz_id and duration are not unique, and I can not figure out how to delete them in that case... My deleting duplicates should only be based on - 
to keep always the first appereance of mz_id until it changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use a helper series and `groupby+first`:

```
df.groupby(df['mz_id'].ne(df['mz_id'].shift()).cumsum()).first().reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
   id mz_id     time duration
0   1     a     0:00     0:10
1   1     b     5:10     1:10
2   1     a  1:10:05     0:15
3   1     b  2:10:05     1:10
4   1     c  3:20:07     0:15
```

Details:
Checking if the next row is same as the current row then doing a `cumsum()` to assign a group to each changed group, then groupby that series and returning first

```
df['mz_id'].ne(df['mz_id'].shift())
```

---

```
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10     True
11     True
```

Hence this will return true for all the first row which has a same value in the next row.

however as @Datanovice points out , in your example the below would also work since you are just taking the first row.

```
df[df['mz_id'].ne(df['mz_id'].shift())]
```

Comment: would `df[df['mz_id'].ne(df['mz_id'].shift())]` also work?

Comment: @Datanovice good point. It would (haven't tested for different usecases but works on the sample data :)  guess it will as long we are looking at a single col

Comment: Thank you both for your time and help. :) 
I have suggestion to expand your answer and explain step by step. Because I didn't find any similar question and I guess that this will be noticed. :)

Comment: @Anajlim done, I think Datanovice's suggestion works great in your example too

Comment: He should also post it an answer. I will give him thumb up. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you want to keep the original index is:

```
df[df['mz_id'] != df['mz_id'].shift()]
```